# Lighting component SLDS formatting to match standard delete

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css, slds

I have the lightning quick action that opens lightning component. Here is the code for the aura lightning component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasRecordId" controller="SalesOrderSendOrderApproval" access="global">

    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <aura:attribute name="order" type="SalesOrder__c" />
    <aura:attribute name="msg" type="String" />
    <aura:handler event="aura:waiting" action="{!c.showSpinner}"/>
    <aura:handler event="aura:doneWaiting" action="{!c.hideSpinner}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Spinner" type="boolean" default="false"/>

    <aura:html tag="style">
    .cuf-content {
                padding: 0 0rem !important;
            }
            .slds-p-around--medium {
                padding: 0rem !important;
            }       
            .slds-modal__content{
                height:unset !important;
                max-height:unset !important;
            }
    </aura:html>

    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.Spinner}">
        <div aura:id="spinnerId" class="slds-spinner_container">
           <div class="slds-spinner--brand  slds-spinner slds-spinner--large slds-is-relative" role="alert">
             <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading</span>
             <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
             <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </aura:if>
      <header class="slds-modal__header">
        <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-modal__title slds-hyphenate">Send Order Approval</h2>
      </header>
      <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium slds-align_absolute-center" id="modal-content-id-1">
        <p>Are you sure you want to send this order for approval?</p>   
      </div>
      <footer class="slds-modal__footer">          
        <lightning:button name='No' label='No' onclick='{!c.handleConfirmDialogNo}'/>
        <lightning:button variant="brand" name='Yes' label='Yes' onclick='{!c.handleConfirmDialogYes}'/>
      </footer>
</aura:component>
```

I've applied the following CSS styles to the component:

```
.THIS.slds-spinner_container {  
    z-index: 10000;
    position: fixed;  
    height: 170px;
    margin:auto; 
  }
```

The component works properly, but I was wondering how to adjust the styling of the component to match how the standard delete looks. Here is a comparison side by side:

[image]

Ideally, I'd like to remove the extra padding here:

[screenshot](https://d.pr/i/7yaqde)

I initially tried adjusting the height of the quick action and it caused an overflow and added scrollbars. The height of the quick action is set to `200px`.

Is there a way to get the look to match the standard delete?

Comment: Along with `slds-modal__content`, you have used `slds-p-around_medium` which I suspect is the cause of padding. By default, SF modals do not have any padding. Have you tried removing it? Also, you can try to use `class="slds-p-around_none"`.

Comment: I tried modifying the class both ways and neither worked. The padding was still there.

Comment: Are you able to inspect the DOM in developer console and figure out which CSS is actually causing the padding?

Comment: I was able to solve the issue by adding the aura:html tag="style" to the component. I've update my original post with the code changes that got it to work in case anyone is interested in the fix that made it work. I also updated the css file in the component. See updated code.